# JPA @OneToOne with same type

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-one

How to annotate my code to have a Person with 2 Addresses :

```
@Entity
public Person {

    // ... other attributes for a person

    @OneToOne
    public Address homeAddress;

    @OneToOne
    public Address workAddress;
}

@Entity
public Address {

    // ... other attributes for an address

    @OneToOne
    public Person person;
}
```

Can I use OneToOne ? 
Should I have to use options on this annotations ?

Comment: Why use the backpointer from address to Person?  If you remove this, your entities make sense assuming that an Address can be shared among many people.  You could just query for the people you are looking for when needed rather than keep them cached in the Address object.  "Select p from Person p where p.workAddress = :address"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible to achieve with `@OneToOne`. The reason:

the persistence provider will have one `Person` id for two entries the `Address` table. This is not sufficient to decide which relation a given `Address` belongs to.

The simplest solution would be to add a `type` field (an enum) to the `Address` entity and map the addresses with `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne`.

In order to get the home address, you would need to iterate over the addresses and check for type.

Alternatively, you could create extra types like `HomeAddress` and `WorkAddress` which would derive from the `Address`. You could then keep the `@OneToOne` relations, but would end up with two additional types.

IMO a cleaner entity relation mapping is not a sufficient reason for doing this, as you are inviting some issues. For example a `HomeAddress` can never be a `WorkAddress`.

**EDIT**: If both `Address` ids are stored in the `Person` table, you should be able to use the`@OneToOne` relation. To ensure deletion of attached Address entities and deletion of orphaned Address entities, you can use cascading and orphan removal:

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Although it might look like this makes sure that there could be no orphaned `Address` records in the DB, it is not entirely true. Orphan removal works only when you remove the referenced entity inside a transaction while the entities are attached. Furthermore it does not work for bulk updates. A `DELETE FROM Person WHERE ...` query will happily delete the Persons and will not touch the connected Addresses.

Comment: If it could help for a best solution, I can use uni-directionnal link from `Person` to `Address`, but I want to be sure that there will not be unused "old" `Address` in the DB. Any solution in that case ?

Comment: @xnopre- well yes, making the relation unidirectional is a good option. please see the edit.

Comment: Yes, my problem is with "bulk" updates : I do some updates on a POJO (i.e. detached object), then a merge and a save (I'm with PlayFramework V1) and the "old" unused Addresses are not removed, but if I good understand, that's normal .... :-(

Comment: @xnopre - yeah, it's quite a straitjacket with JPA sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

OneToOne implies a table has a foreign key to another, but you haven't specified which, and are implying that it isn't a real 1:1 situation from address->person.  Will employee have a workAddress_ID and homeAddress_id field?  In which case, there are two different 1:1s.  What isn't valid is your address->Employee 1:1 as there is no way for it to use both the workAddress_ID and homeAddress_id relationships.  You could work around this by having address have 2 OneToOnes that are private, and then a public getPerson method used by the application that returns the one that isn't null.  Setting the person would require looking at the passed in person object ot know which of the Address 1:1's to populate, but it wouldn't matter as much since they wouldn't control the relationship:

```
public Address {

    // ... other attributes for an address

    @OneToOne(mappedby="workAddress")
    private Person workPerson;
    @OneToOne(mappedby="homeAddress")
    private Person homePerson;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return workPerson==null? homePerson:workPerson;
    }
    public void setPerson(Person p) {
        workPerson=null;
        homePerson=null;
        if (p !=null) {
            if (p.getHomeAddress()==this) {
              homePerson=p;
            } else {
              workPerson=p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisions : I'm working with `PlayFramework V1`, my objects are extending `play.db.jpa.Model` and have an "Id" field. Thanks for the solution, but I don't want to modify `Address` adding 2 or more `Person` field